# C++ functions and random number

Tags: c++, function, random, numbers

When I write this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int random = std::rand() % 9 + 1;



int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
   if(random==1 || random ==2 || random == 3){
        cout << "Wolf" << endl;
   }  else if(random==4 || random ==5 || random == 6){
        cout << "Bear" << endl;
   }  else if(random==7 || random ==8 || random == 9){
        cout << "Pig" << endl;
   }
}
```

Every time I run it I get something else printed(Wolf, Pig or Bear), like I wanted.
But when I add this function in my code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int random = std::rand() % 9 + 1;

void func(){
   if(random==1 || random ==2 || random == 3){
        cout << "Wolff" << endl;

   }  else if(random==4 || random ==5 || random == 6){
        cout << "Bearr" << endl;

   }  else if(random==7 || random ==8 || random == 9){
        cout << "Pigg" << endl;

   }
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));


   if(random==1 || random ==2 || random == 3){
        cout << "Wolf" << endl;
        func();
   }  else if(random==4 || random ==5 || random == 6){
        cout << "Bear" << endl;
        func();
   }  else if(random==7 || random ==8 || random == 9){
        cout << "Pig" << endl;
        func();
   }
}
```

I want every time I run it to get printed something else like Bear Bearr, Wolf Wolff or Pig Pigg.But with this function whenever I run it I get the same result.What is the problem?
Please help me, I'm new in C++.

Comment: I don't believe that you always "get something else printed"; see my answer. Also, this code doesn't even compile for me on Posix, since `random` is already defined in `cstdlib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global initializers are executed *before* `main` is called. So you never reseed your PRNG, and thus always draw the same "random" numbers.

That said, I don't believe that either of your code pieces produce different output with each run, since they have the same initialization order problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand: the two programs are identical except for the fact that some additional function calls are executed in the second program that only read the value of `random`. Why should that make any difference? What I find really surprising is the OP's statement that "*Every time I run it I get something else printed(Wolf, Pig or Bear), like I wanted*". I would say that can't possibly be true

Comment: @AndyProwl: You're right. I don't actually believe what the OP claims about the original code. Let's wait for clarification.

Comment: Sorry, in first code variable random was supposed to be in main. :(

Comment: @user2529389: well, fix your post then! And I suppose you can see how my answer applies (but I can update it if you like).

Comment: @user2529389 You can edit your question to update it with this new information. There's a little `edit` link at the bottom, or you can go to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17394411/edit.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changing to match your stated goal of "bear", "bearr", "pig", "pigg".

```
int random = std::rand() % 9 + 1;
```

declares a global variable called "random" which is assigned a value during startup, before main(). The value will be the (default return value of rand() modulo'd by 9) plus one. It does not automatically change.

What you appear to be looking for is

```
int random()
{
    return (std::rand() % 9) + 1;
}
```

which defines a function that calls rand, modulos the value by 9 and then returns one. EDIT: To see the same value inside the "func()" function, pass it by value or reference as a function parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int random() {
    return (std::rand() % 9) + 1;
}

void func(int randNo){
    switch (randNo) {
        case 1: case 2: case 3:
            cout << "Wolff" << endl;
        break;
        case 4: case 5: case 6:
            cout << "Bearr" << endl;
        break;
        case 7: case 8: case 9:
            cout << "Pigg" << endl;
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    int randNo = random();
            switch (randNo) {
        case 1: case 2: case 3:
            cout << "Wolf" << endl;
            func(randNo);
        break;
        case 4: case 5: case 6:
            cout << "Bear" << endl;
            func(randNo);
        break;
        case 7: case 8: case 9:
            cout << "Pig" << endl;
            func(randNo);
        break;
    }

            cout << "And now for something completely different." << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cout << i << ": ";
        func(random());
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants `Bear Bearr, Wolf Wolff or Pig Pigg`, this might print something else. Obviously the easiest thing to do there would be to change the `cout` statements in `main`. If the end goal is more complicated and involves another function that requires the random number, it can be passed as a parameter.